# Insert multiple content in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created a form for user add a products and set their prices on each store.

There are three simple databases:

```
Products:
- id
- token
- name

Stores:
- id
- name

Prices:
- id
- product_token
- store_id
- price
```

My first idea for the form is create a `foreach` loop with Stores data inside the form:

```
foreach ($stores_result as $row) {
    $store_id = $row->id;
    $store = $row->name;

     <a class="add-store" href="#" data-store="<?php echo $store_id; ?>"><?php echo $loja; ?></a>
}
```

When user click on a store link, jQuery add a input to the form, like this:

```
    field = '<input type="text" name="price" class="form-control">';
    $(this).hide().parent().after(field);
```

When user submit the form, I'm using PDO to store data in database:

```
    $token = uniqid($_POST['product'], true);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO products (token, name) VALUES(:token, :name)');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':token' => $token,
        ':nome' => $_POST['product'],
    ));

    $stmt2 = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO prices(product_token, price) VALUES(:product_token, :price)');
    $stmt2->execute(array(
        ':product_token' => $token,
        ':price' =>$_POST['price']
    ));
```

My question is:

1. How can I insert in price table the id of selected store?
2. Why product_token is set to 0 in prices table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After the first query check the last insert it. $la= $smat2->lastInsertId(); then insert $id in the price table. On your #2 I thik token column is a of type in and token is a string not a number. You may have to alter you table to the correct column type. Your sql_more is not set to strict and this is probably why it is not giving you and error (show create table will help here :))

Comment: @Mike You're correct about token column. I fix it. And how about #1? How can I send select store id? Is possible to include two values (price and store id) in a single input?

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding Question #1**

After the first query check the last insert it. `$product_id = $stmt->lastInsertId()` then insert $id in the price table.

```
$token = uniqid($_POST['product'], true);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO products (token, name) VALUES(:token, :name)');
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':token' => $token,
    ':nome' => $_POST['product'],
));
$product_id = $stmt->lastInsertId();

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO prices(product_id, product_token, price) VALUES(:product_id, :product_token, :price)');
$stmt2->execute(array(
    ':product_id' => $product_id,
    ':product_token' => $token,
    ':price' =>$_POST['price']
));
```

Regarding your note above. you will need your new column to be of the type string and you can change the line I added to something like this:

`$product_id = $stmt->lastInsertId() . '_'.$_POST['price'] ;`

the above line will give you something like 12_19.99

**Regarding #2** 
I think the token column is a of type integer and token is a string not a number. if your sql_mode is not strict then it will truncate the string.
You may have to alter you table to the correct column type.